# Why isn't it possible to decode a server seed using nonce

Tags: encryption, hash, decode, sha256, sha512

I have 0 knowledge as to the way SHA256 or SHA512 function, and I am also uneducated on the similarities/differences between them.

I'm hoping to grasp the most basic understanding of why a server seed can't be cracked using the server seed hash, client seed, and most importantly a bunch of nonced outcomes.

For example,
Lets say you are playing a provably fair game, which provides a server seed hash, and a client seed.

Each game round outcome is determined based on a publically available equation which factors in the "unhashed" / "original" (pardon my terminology) server seed, the client seed, and a "nonce"

Each new game round adds 1 to the nonce.

So after let's say 1000 rounds, the server and client seeds remain the same, and the nonce is 1000, increasing by 1 every round.

The game is considered provably fair, because you are provided the server seed hash, and once you change to a new seed pair, the last secret server seed is revealed so that you can verify all the previous rounds

So once you change to a new seed, a new server seed hash is provided, and nonce increases by 1 every round until you want to verify again, at which point the seed pair is changed again, and the previous unhashed server seed is revealed.

Now sorry for the long explanation, but I thought that might help to understand what I'm trying to grasp in my question.

Q: If you have the equation which uses the seed pair to determine the round outcomes, (a static equation), and you have the client seed, and a list of previous round outcomes which are all based on an incrementing nonce,
Why then could you not "brute force" the unhashed server seed?

I know I said the server seed is hidden until after you change to a new seed pair, but okay in the most basic way possible,

Lets say the equation to determine the round outcomes is
server seed (X) * client seed (Y) * nonce (Z) = round outcome

To phrase my question another way,
Lets say you're 1000 rounds into the same seed pair, or 10,000 rounds or whatever. Why can't you "brute force" the the value of the server seed by throwing every possible seed into the equation, until you come across the one that matches the same outcomes for those 1,000 nonced outcomes, and then use that to pre determine the outcome for round 1001 and beyond?

Hopefully you understand my long question

Edit: you are given everything but the server seed. So after 1000's of rounds, why couldn't the outcomes of those previous rounds be used to determine  what the seed is?

I get that there's an incredibly large amount of possibilities, but its not an infinite amount.
So the main thing Im trying to understand is why SHA256 / 512 is stated as being "uncrackable"

I understand something like an account password, you cant just brute force as long as the server has some type of failed attempt lockout function, because you only get so many tries before the account gets locked, and no more attempts are permitted.
In that case, I can understand why that might be considered uncrackable, or at least not "brute force able"
But if you have a list of final values which were determined using a client seed, server seed, and nonce, and you have everything but the server seed,
You could hypothetically "guess" the server seed that results in the same round outcomes, and disregard the server seed hash.
Theres no account lockout type of dilema, so why is this hashing impossible to decode?

The way i see it, if you had enough "luck", or processing power, it would be very much possible,
This:
[[[[Maybe not to "decode" the hash, but rather to "determine" the seed, right? The impossibility of Decoding the hash is one thing but surely with the other given info, the original seed isnt "undetermineable"]]]]]

Comment: A carefully designed hash function that using SHA-256 or -512 would only be breakable by brute force. In that case the "server seed" must have enough entropy so that brute force becomes computationally infeasible. Usually entropy is measured in bits, and usually 128 bits (= 16 bytes) is considered roughly the minimum entropy needed for long-lived secrets and 256 bits is considered more than enough. Your game scenario is definitely a very short-lived secret, so 128 bits should be fine. 128 bits obtained from a cryptographic-quality RNG should contain about 128 bits of entropy.